# No reputation from accepted answer

Tags: support, reputation, community-wiki

I answered this question on StackOverflow: [Javascript to Dynamically Create Spaces/Folders in Alfresco Doesn't Work Correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077597/javascript-to-dynamically-create-spaces-folders-in-alfresco-doesnt-work-correct/12092484#12092484)
Then a bounty of +50 is offered on this question. As the question is changed by the owner, I change my answer in accordance with the changed question. I changed my answer 13 times. It shows this:

**community wiki
13 revs
swemon**

After the bounty period, the owner accepts my answer. As far as I know, when one's answer is accepted, one gains +15 reputation. But my reputation has not changed.

Comment: Look at [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Comment: Yeah. It writes more than 10 times edited by owner, the post becomes community wiki post.

Comment: Note for any new readers stumbling across this old question: the automatic conversion of posts to community wiki due to too many edits, as happened in this case, [was removed in 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228947). The only ways in which a question or an answer can now become a community wiki are described in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't gain reputation on community wiki posts, which **includes** the reputation from it being accepted by the OP. The only reputation you can gain from a CW answer is a bounty award.

Comment: Also I do not get bounty award because the question owner accepts my answer after giving bounty award to another person whose answer the most upvote. :D

Comment: When was this made? `:o` I thought only vote up and down are not affected.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Pretty sure it's always functioned this way since community wiki was created. This answer is from 2012, so it's not exactly a recent change.

Comment: @animuson Tried answering a question in CW mode, and got slightly taken aback that I didn't get rep for getting my answer accepted. Woah! :)